# Trying to find a way to store variable amounts of data for a variable number of items (WITHOUT USING A LINKED LIST)

Tags: c, arrays, list

I am writing a C program in which two files are read: file1.txt is a large text file (a novel for example) and the other file2.txt is a list of words. So far my program scans the entire file, line by line, searching for each of these word. Now I am in need of a way to store the line number where each instance of each word appears.

For example, say file2.txt contains two words , "apple" and "pear". I would now need my program to create two sets of data storing the line numbers where each of these words appears in file1.txt.

One solution I have thought of is two create an array for each word in file2.txt and each element of these arrays would be the line numbers:

```
apple[5] = {6, 12, 28, 44}

pear[3]  = {10, 37}
```

Is there any way this can be done? i.e. Is it possible to create a variable number of arrays based on how many words are in file2.txt and each of these arrays to be of length based on how many lines the word appears in?

Comment: You could make 2 passes of the file. Pass 1 counts the word occurences, you then allocate memory, pass 2 fills in the detail.

Comment: For each word, store a pointer to its data and its current count-of-data. If the count increases, use `realloc` to resize. (This can be made slightly less painful by storing a `max` as well, and allocating in larger chunks.)

Answer (score 0):

in general,

```
#define MAX_WORD_LEN (50)
struct  wordCount
{
    int  Count;
    char Word[MAX_WORD_LEN];
};

struct wordCount *pWordCount = NULL;
int numWordCount = 0;


read file2 (the one containing the word list)
for each extractedWord
    if word not already in list (it should not be)
        realloc ( pWordCount, sizeof(struct wordCount)* (numWordCount+1) )
        if realloc successful
            pWordCount[numWordCount].count = 0;
            memset( pWOrdCount[numWOrdCount].word, 0x00, MAX_WORD_LEN );
            strncpy(pWordCount[numWordCount], extractedWord, MAX_WORD_LEN-1 )
            numWordCount++;

        endif
    endif
end for


now you have an array of struct wordCount that you can search  
for each word extracted from file1
When a word, extracted from file1 matches a word in the pWordCount array
then
    pWordCount[currentIndex].count++;
```